# Unsure how the current is traveling in the circuit. Maybe a short?

Tags: ac, relay

**Background:**

I'm having some difficulties with the washing machine (WD80J6410AW/EU) UK

It's blown the line-in PCB fuse on two separate main PCBs. I got a replacement PCB when it first stopped working, which seemed to at least allow me to power it on, but on the first use, it failed again. I traced the issue to a blown fuse on the main PCB. After replacing that I can get everything to turn on again, but I'm sure it will blow again if we try to run a cycle.

**What I can't figure out:**

Given the below wiring diagram, while only connecting up the green dots (all other cables disconnected), I'm getting power to both PCBs. Then the relay marked "power relay" will switch.

I would think you need the power into board 1 (at PW) to run the 12 V transformer, to power the line to switch the relay to power everything else.

But just with the below green dots lines connected (not all tracked lines), the relay will switch, the LEDs come on, board 2 gets power, the LEDs come on.

Now I can't decide if this is meant to happen, and I'm misunderstanding, or the CAUSE of my blowing fuse, a short somewhere, that is putting live current in the wrong direction?

My AC knowledge is pretty rusty, but probing voltage on the REACTOR is fine solid 220 V, but I am getting 200 V->210 V fluctuating if I probe between MR (1)(2) after disconnecting it, which technically puts the meter in series if everything is connected with no shorts. I don't know if that's because I'm measuring voltage in series, or if there is actually 200 V->210 V and I'm measuring a short in parallel.

[image: Tracked Version]

NOTE: There is no "hidden" connection between the two boards displayed, only via the green dots lines, which is why I can't understand where the power is traveling from to switch the relay.

**The relay is a GT-1A-12D**

[image: Relay In Question]

**Real picture of PCB**

Green squares are connected, everything else has been disconnected for this question/confusion.

[image: Picture of PCB]

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: What exactly does "probing voltage on the REACTOR is fine solid 220 V" mean? are you measuring from Neutral to each reactor terminal, or are you measuring from one reactor terminal to the other?

Comment: I probed Neutral after the NOISE FILTER to output of the REACTOR

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. I think.

Behind the relay is a bridge rectifier. I managed to probe a pin from that to the a top pin on the relay. So the bridge rectifier is connected to the through-hole pins of the relay under the pcb.

The second PCB powers the bridge rectifier, which then switches the relay. This then allows the second PCB to bypass the bridge rectifier as it's main route to neutral, which is why my relay switch's on very quickly and lights come on, then it all turns off. Normally I'm guessing another circuit takes over holding the relay closed.

There must also be some protection that's stopping the relay going on and off rapidly.

Doesn't explain my blowing fuses, but at least know this is normal behaviour and one more thing off the list.